# Cropping and combining two images on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've coded following two methods to combine images that are HTTP POSTed to the server:

```
// Crops two squares out of two separate images
// And then combines them into single image that's returned as byte[]
private byte[] combineImages(HttpPostedFileBase[] itemPayload)
{
    try
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 400, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
        using (var img1 = Image.FromStream(itemPayload[0].InputStream))
        using (var img2 = Image.FromStream(itemPayload[1].InputStream))
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            RectangleF img1Params = getCropParams(img1);
            g.DrawImage(img1, new RectangleF(0, 0, 400, 400), img1Params, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            RectangleF img2Params = getCropParams(img2);
            g.DrawImage(img2, new RectangleF(400, 0, 400, 400), img2Params, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 90L);
            bitmap.Save(ms, ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().Single(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid), encoderParameters);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new byte[0];
    }
}

private RectangleF getCropParams(Image img)
{
    var rect = new RectangleF();
    if (img.Width > img.Height)
    {
        rect.X = (img.Width / 2) - (img.Height / 2);
        rect.Width = (img.Width / 2) + (img.Height / 2) - rect.X;
        rect.Y = 0;
        rect.Height = img.Height;
    }
    else
    {
        rect.X = 0;
        rect.Width = img.Width;
        rect.Y = (img.Height / 2) - (img.Width / 2);
        rect.Height = (img.Height / 2) + (img.Width / 2) - rect.Y;
    }

    return rect;
}
```

It produces results I expect, but I was curious if my implementation could be improved. I am specifically interested in three things:

1. Do you see any potential memory leaks?
2. Do you think code will be performing well when it comes to scalability
3. Is there a component like [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) that can do this?

Comment: Instead of `return new byte[0]`, I'd have a class-level field `private static readonly byte[] emptyImage = new byte[0]` and then just `return emptyImage`. You may also want to do similarly with your `encoderParameters` so it isn't created on each call as it seems to be invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment above, I'd also follow Microsoft's naming guidelines and have the method names be `PascalCase`d. Plus, I'm not a huge fan of mutable `structs`, preferring to initialize them via provided constructors. So I came up with the following:

```
public static class ImageCombiner
{
    private static readonly EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    private static readonly RectangleF sizeLocation1 = new RectangleF(0.0F, 0.0F, 400.0F, 400.0F);

    private static readonly RectangleF sizeLocation2 = new RectangleF(400.0F, 0.0F, 400.0F, 400.0F);

    private static readonly ImageCodecInfo jpgDecoder = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().Single(codec => codec.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);

    private static readonly byte[] emptyImage = new byte[0];

    static ImageCombiner()
    {
        encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 90L);
    }

    // Crops two squares out of two separate images
    // And then combines them into single image that's returned as byte[]
    public static byte[] CombineImages(IList<HttpPostedFileBase> itemPayload)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(800, 400, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
            using (var img1 = Image.FromStream(itemPayload[0].InputStream))
            using (var img2 = Image.FromStream(itemPayload[1].InputStream))
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                g.DrawImage(img1, sizeLocation1, GetCropParams(img1), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                g.DrawImage(img2, sizeLocation2, GetCropParams(img2), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                bitmap.Save(ms, jpgDecoder, encoderParameters);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return emptyImage;
        }
    }

    private static RectangleF GetCropParams(Image img)
    {
        return img.Width > img.Height
            ? new RectangleF(
                    (img.Width / 2) - (img.Height / 2),
                    0.0F,
                    2 * (img.Height / 2),
                    img.Height)
            : new RectangleF(
                    0.0F,
                    (img.Height / 2) - (img.Width / 2),
                    img.Width,
                    2 * (img.Width / 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do away with the extra calculations. `((img.Width / 2) + (img.Height / 2)) - ((img.Width / 2) - (img.Height / 2))` is equal to `img.Height`.

Similarly `((img.Height / 2) + (img.Width / 2)) - ((img.Height / 2) - (img.Width / 2))` equals `img.Width`.

Comment: @TanzeelKazi while you are correct the calculations can be simplified, what you say they can be simplified to is somewhat off. For instance, an image with an odd `Width` or `Height` will wind up rounding down when said and done. I have edited my answer to show a simplified calculation that is accurate.